# Faster exhaustive research using numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, parallel-processing, brute-force

I'm trying to maximize the minimum between two function using exhaustive research, this solution work but loop in python consumes a lot of computing time. is there an efficient way to use numpy (mesh grid or vectorize) to solve this problem?

**Code :**

Functions below are used in the exhaustive research method

```
import numpy as np

def F1(x):
  return (x/11)**10

def F2(x,y,z):
  return z+x/y

def F3(x,y,z,a,b,c):
  return ((x+y)**z)/((a-b)**c)
```

Exhaustive research method take 6 parameter (scalar or 1D array). for the moment I just want to compute my code on scalar, then I can use another function to browse those parameter if they are 1D array.

```
def B_F(P1, P2, P3,P4, P5, P6) :
  # initializing my optimal parameters 
  a_Opt, b_opt, c_opt, obj_opt = 0, 0, 0, 0 
  # feasible set
  a = np.linspace(0.0,1.0,10)
  b = np.linspace(0.0,100.0,100)  
  c = np.linspace(0.0,100.0,100)  
       
  for i in a:
      for j in b:
        for k in c:
          #if constraint is respected
          if P1*k+P2*j+2*(i*k*j) <= F1(P3):
              # calculate the max min of the two function
              f_1 = F2(i,k,P6)
              f_2 = F3(i,k,j,10,P4,P5)
              min_f = np.minimum(f_1, f_2)
              # extract optimal parameters and objective function
              if obj_opt <= min_f :
                  a_Opt = i 
                  b_opt = j
                  c_opt = k 
                  obj_opt = min_f

  exhaustive_research = np.array([[obj_opt, a_Opt, b_opt, c_opt]])          
  
  return  exhaustive_research
```

Comment: I don't think `if P1*k+P2*j+2*(i*k*j) <= F1(P3):` is valid for 1D arrays...

Comment: Also please format your code correctly... and provide a [mre]

Comment: and do you realize you are trying to compute 10**11 values? Do you think you have enough RAM to store such a big meshgrid?

Comment: I used another function to browse the 1 D array, for now I juste wanna compute it for a scalar

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I can compute less then `10**11` like `10**4`.. it can work with my RAM

Comment: @Julien I changed my post, hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
A,B,C = np.meshgrid(a,b,c)
mask = P1*C+P2*B+2*(A*B*C) <= F1(P3)
A = A[mask]
B = B[mask]
C = C[mask]
  
f_1 = F2(A,C,P6)
f_2 = F3(A,C,B,10,P4,P5)
min_f = np.minimum(f_1, f_2)
ind = np.argmax(min_f)
obj_opt, a_Opt, b_opt, c_opt = min_f[ind], A[ind], B[ind], C[ind]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. At the end you mean c[ind] or C[ind]? and how if P1, P2, P3... was 1D array, is it possible to solve it in the same way?

Comment: Yes `C[ind]` not `c[ind]`, sorry for the typo, corrected. Not sure what you want to do if th Ps are arrays since, as I said, `if P1*k+P2*j+2*(i*k*j) <= F1(P3):` would throw...